# Can a channel have multiple consumers?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure

Reading through the [Core Async walkthrough](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/examples/walkthrough.clj) I don't think I saw this use case. I have one producer and many identical consumers.

```
(def mychan (chan))
(defn my-expensive-fn [arg] (prn-expensively arg))

; four identical consumers
(go (while true (my-expensive-fn (<!! mychan))))
(go (while true (my-expensive-fn (<!! mychan))))
(go (while true (my-expensive-fn (<!! mychan))))
(go (while true (my-expensive-fn (<!! mychan))))

; something generating lots of items
(doseq [item in lots-of-items]
    (something-expensive)
    (>!! mychan item))
```

1. Is it valid?
2. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this rather than repeating (copy-pasting or in a loop) the consumer-calling code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid to read from a channel from as many places as you like. Each message will be read by at most one of them.

Instead of copy-pasting the code, you can create identical blocks in a loop.

```
(dotimes [_ 4]
  (go
    (while true
      (my-expensive-fn (<!! mychan)))))
```

the one issue you will see here is that the loop has no condition that will stop the recursion, and it makes more sense to at least stop if the channel closes.

```
(dotimes [_ 4]
   (go-loop [job (<!! mychan)]
     (when (some? job)
       (my-expensive-fn job)
       (recur (<!! mychan)))))
```

A closed channel instantly returns nil, and this version will stop when it gets nil, rather than going into a tight loop repeatedly consuming and dispatching on nil.

Comment: Consider using `go-loop` instead of `go`+`loop`.